# Adding HTML5 video controls to Clickable video?

Tags: html, video

Is there a way to make just the video clickable to the below code and keep the controls separate?

When I click on one of the controls with the below code it clicks on the link as well.

```
    <video width="300" height="250" controls muted autoplay
 onclick='window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/","_blank");'> <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, the controls are considered part of the video element, so if the link is being applied to the video element, the link will also be applied to the controls. You could create the controls separately instead of using the controls parameter.

Comment: the other solution would be to put a transparent div over the video and put the onclick on that, so you can size it to avoid the controls